# How to check a file exist in the folder using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to check a file exist or not in the folder, if exist it will create a new folder. I tried my code, but Its not working. I can not create a new folder, but I already make sure that I have the file that I check.

```
$WKFD = "$b-$timestamp"
$Path_2 = "C:\Users\Documents\Convert\$WKFD"

if([System.IO.File]::Exists("$Path_2\t.txt")-ne $true)
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Path_2+2
}
```

Comment: `New-Item` with `-Force` creates the folder if it doesn't exists, no need of `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`New-Item` with `-Force` creates the folder if it doesn't exists, no need of `if` statement.
If you want to check, use `Test-Path` to check the folder availability.

```
$WKFD = "$b-$timestamp"
$Path_2 = "C:\Users\Documents\Convert\$WKFD"

if(Test-Path -Path "$Path_2\t.txt"){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $NewFolder
}
```

What do you meant by `$Path_2+2` ?

Answer (score 4):

As an example to test if a given item exist you can check for the path.

```
if(Test-Path 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 
   2018.3.5\bin\pycharm.exe'){
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $yourPath
}
```

Hope it helps! BR

Answer (score 2):

Use this to check if the folder exists:

```
$folderName = "something"
$path = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\" + $folderName

if (Test-Path -Path $path){
    #Folder exists, check for existance of file
}else{
    #Folder doesn't exist, create it
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $path
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

If file test1.txt exists then a folder named newDir is created, else no action is performed.

```
if(Test-Path C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test\test1.txt -PathType Leaf)
{
    Write-Output "File exists"
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\Users\Username\Desktop\test\newDir
}
else {
    Write-Output "File does not exist"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use

```
Test-Path 'pathToFile/FileName'
```

It returns True or False depending on whether the file exits or not